# Problema Librería Pattern en Python

Tags: python, regex

Revisé otros hilos y no encontré respuesta
El código sé que está bien porque es un aporte de cátedra. Tengo Pattern versión 3.6 Algunas opciones las reconoce (por ejemplo singularize o pluralize).
Ahora, ejecuto este código:

El error está en mis paquetes. Y no sé dónde.
Intenté desistalar el pattern y reinstalarlo pero no hubo ninguna modificación en el resultado. 
Mi versión de python es 3.8

```
from pattern.es import verbs
from pattern.es import parse, split

def solo_los_verbos(frase):
    s = parse(frase).split()
    for cada in s:
        for c in cada:
            if c[1] == 'VB':
                print("{}: es un verbo".format(c[0]))
            else:
                print("{}: NO es un verbo".format(c[0]))

def main():
    print("-"*20)
    frase = "Yo me quedo en casa!!"
    solo_los_verbos(frase)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

y me da esta respuesta:

```
--------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 609, in _read
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "d:\Informatica\Seminario Lenguaje Python\Teoricos y Prácticos\clase6\clase6\ejemplos\verbos.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
    File "d:\Informatica\Seminario Lenguaje Python\Teoricos y Prácticos\clase6\clase6\ejemplos\verbos.py", line 22, in main
    solo_los_verbos(frase)
    File "d:\Informatica\Seminario Lenguaje Python\Teoricos y Prácticos\clase6\clase6\ejemplos\verbos.py", line 9, in solo_los_verbos
    s = parse(frase).split()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\es\__init__.py", line 236, in 
parse
    return parser.parse(s, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 1172, in parse
    s[i] = self.find_tags(s[i], **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\es\__init__.py", line 209, in 
find_tags
    return _Parser.find_tags(self, tokens, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 1113, in find_tags
    lexicon = kwargs.get("lexicon", self.lexicon or {}),
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 376, in __len__
    return self._lazy("__len__")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 368, in _lazy
    self.load()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 625, in load
    dict.update(self, (x.split(" ")[:2] for x in _read(self._path) if len(x.split(" ")) > 1))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 625, in <genexpr>
    dict.update(self, (x.split(" ")[:2] for x in _read(self._path) if len(x.split(" ")) > 1))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una diferencia entre python 3.6 y 3.8 que rompe `pattern.es` https://github.com/clips/pattern/issues/243

La solucion del dia de hoy es

```py
def main():
    """Solo necessitas hacer eso una vez para evitar el bug"""
    try:
        solo_los_verbos("bug workaround")
    except:
        pass
    """Continua tu codigo normal"""

    print("-"*20)
    frase = "Yo me quedo en casa!!"
    solo_los_verbos(frase)
```

Comment: Lo he probado y evita el error pero no devuelve nada. Es decir que directamente pasa al except y sale mediante el pass.

Comment: @IvánKnopoff segunda llamada debe devolver el resultado